# Expectation of product of stochastic integrals

Tags: expectation, brownian-motion, stochastic-integrals

I am trying to evaluate the following expectation:

\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \left( \int_{t_2}^{t_3} \sigma_\tau dW_\tau \right) \left( \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \sigma_\tau^2 d\tau \right) ,
\end{equation}

where $W_\tau$ is a Weiner process, $\sigma_\tau$ is a locally bounded, non-negative stochastic process, adapted to the filtration generated by $W_\tau$, and $t_1 \leq t_2 < t_3 \leq t_4$. Currently my best effort is as follows:

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
& \mathbb{E} \left( \int_{t_2}^{t_3} \sigma_\tau dW_\tau \right) \left( \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \sigma_\tau^2 d\tau \right) \\
=& \mathbb{E} \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \left( \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \sigma_s^2 ds \right) \sigma_\tau \mathbf{1}_{t_2 < \tau \leq t_3} dW_\tau \\
 =& \mathbb{E} \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \left( \int_{t_1}^{\tau} \sigma_s^2 ds \right) \sigma_\tau \mathbf{1}_{t_2 < \tau \leq t_3} dW_\tau + \mathbb{E} \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \left( \int_{\tau}^{t_4} \sigma_s^2 ds \right) \sigma_\tau \mathbf{1}_{t_2 < \tau \leq t_3} dW_\tau \\ 
 =& \mathbb{E} \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \left( \int_{t_1}^{\tau} \sigma_s^2 ds \right) \sigma_\tau \mathbf{1}_{t_2 < \tau \leq t_3} dW_\tau + \mathbb{E} \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \left( \int_{t_1}^{\tau} \sigma_s \mathbf{1}_{t_2 < s \leq t_3} dW_s \right) \sigma_\tau^2 d\tau \\ 
 =& \mathbb{E} \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \left( \int_{t_1}^{\tau} \sigma_s^2 ds \right) \sigma_\tau \mathbf{1}_{t_2 < \tau \leq t_3} \mathbb{E} dW_\tau | \mathcal{F}_\tau + \mathbb{E} \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \left( \int_{t_1}^{\tau} \sigma_s \mathbf{1}_{t_2 < s \leq t_3} \mathbb{E} dW_s | \mathcal{F}_\tau \right) \sigma_\tau^2 d\tau \\ 
 =& 0 ,
\end{split}
\end{equation}
where I'm using Fubini/Tonelli in line 4, and the law of iterated expectations in line 5, conditioning on the filtration up to time $\tau$. Stochastic integrals is not a subject I am that familiar with, so I wanted to ask two questions:

1) Is my application of Fubini/Tonelli in line 4 valid?

2) Is there an easier way to evaluate this expectation? Perhaps a well-known theorem that turns it into a one-liner...

Comment: 1) This is more or less correct, however, the last equality is false. In fact, the second expectation is not zero in general: $dW_s$ is $\mathcal F_\tau$-measurable, so you can omit the conditional expectation. 
2) There's no simple way to calculate this in general. One can use the Clark-Ocone formula to deduce that it is equal to
$$
\int_{t_2}^{t_3}\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_s \int_s^{t_4} D_s \sigma_u^2 du\right]ds,
$$
where $D_s$ is the stochastic derivative.

Comment: @zhoraster Thanks for responding. I see your point about $dW_s$ and $\mathcal{F}_\tau$. Is there an additional modelling assumption I could make up the top that would result in the initial expectation evaluating to zero? If there is and you can turn it into an answer I'd be happy to award the bounty.

Comment: There is no such assumption. Looking at the expression I wrote, you can see that the only feasible assumption could be that $D_s \sigma_u = 0, u\ge s$. This means that $\sigma_u$ is independent of $W_s$ for $s<u\wedge t_3$. However, it also has to be independent of $W_s-W_u$ for $u\ge s$ in order for Ito integral to be well defined. So the only feasible assumption is that $\sigma_u$ is independent of the whole path $\{W_s,s\le t_3\}$ (in which case it is rather obvious that the expectation is $0$).

Comment: @zhoraster Ah. I understand now. If you want to turn those two comments into an answer (copy/paste) I'd be happy to award the bounty. Thanks again for taking the time to respond.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that $\sigma$ is good enough (stochastically differentiable), by the Clark--Ocone formula,
$$
\sigma^2_u = \mathbb E[\sigma_u^2] + \int_0^u \mathbb E[D_s \sigma_u^2\mid \mathcal F_s] dW_s.
$$
Hence, denoting $a = \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \mathbb E[\sigma_\tau^2] d\tau$ and using the stochastic Fubini theorem,
$$
\int_{t_1}^{t_4} \sigma_u^2 du =  a + \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \int_0^u \mathbb E[D_s \sigma_u^2\mid \mathcal F_s] dW_s\,du \\
= a + \int_0^{t_4} \int_{s\vee t_1}^{t_4} \mathbb E[D_s \sigma_u^2\mid \mathcal F_s]du\, dW_s.
$$
Consequently,
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E} \left( \int_{t_2}^{t_3} \sigma_s dW_s \right) \left( \int_{t_1}^{t_4} \sigma_s^2 ds \right)  = \int_{t_2}^{t_3}\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_s \int_s^{t_4} \mathbb E[D_s \sigma_u^2\mid \mathcal F_s] du\right]du\\ = \int_{t_2}^{t_3}\mathbb{E}\left[\sigma_s \int_s^{t_4} D_s \sigma_u^2 du\right]du,
\end{equation}
where the last equality is thanks to the $\mathcal F_s$-measurability of $\sigma_s$.

The only feasible assumption on $\sigma$ turning the last expectation to zero seems to be $D_s\sigma_u^2 = 0$ for $s<u\wedge t_4$, which implies that $\sigma_u$ is independent of $\{W_s,s\le t_4\}$. Under this assumption the equality of the expectation in question to zero is easy to see directly, without referring to stochastic derivatives.